# aclocal.m4 not generated by aclocal

Tags: autotools, autoconf

## Introduction

I'm trying to make a bare-bones autotools project. I'm adapting from this tutorial:
https://crypto.bi/autotools/

I have all the required files (I think) and run `aclocal --verbose` and I get a lot of output, most of which is probably not too helpful, save one line I think which is relevant:

```
...
aclocal: found macro AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE in /usr/share/aclocal-1.13/init.m4: 23
...
```

After this program finishes, there isn't any `aclocal.m4` created, and from what I understand, there should be.

## Details

After running `aclocal`, if I run `automake --add-missing`, I get the following error:

```
configure.ac: error: no proper invocation of AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE was found.
configure.ac: You should verify that configure.ac invokes AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE,
configure.ac: that aclocal.m4 is present in the top-level directory,
configure.ac: and that aclocal.m4 was recently regenerated (using aclocal)
automake: error: no 'Makefile.am' found for any configure output
automake: Did you forget AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile]) in configure.ac?
```

## Files

I have the following `configure.ac`

```
AC_INIT([YOURPROJECT], [1.0])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([.])
AC_INIT_AUTOMAKE
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AC_PROG_CC
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h])
AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

and the following `Makefile.am`:

```
AM_LDFLAGS=
AM_CPPFLAGS=
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS=-I m4
bin_PROGRAMS=main
main_SOURCES=main.c
main_LDADD=
```

## Question

How can I generate that `aclocal.m4` file?

Comment: As a rule, always run `autoreconf` and have that worry about what tools to call and in which sequence, never call `autoconf` or `automake` or `aclocal` or `autoheader´ or whatever manually. Also, the crypto.bi examples use very outdated commands, very weird macro sequences. There are better introductions on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your `configure.ac` to something which has a chance of working:

```
AC_PREREQ([2.69])
AC_INIT([YOURPROJECT], [1.0])
AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR([my-main.c])
AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS([m4])
AC_CONFIG_HEADERS([config.h])
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([])

AC_PROG_CC
AC_CHECK_HEADERS([stdlib.h])

AC_CONFIG_FILES([Makefile])
AC_OUTPUT
```

The main change:

- `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` does not start with `AC_`. Not finding `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` is exactly what your `automake` error message is complaining about. So this should make it possible to generate an `aclocal.m4` file.

Additional changes:

- `AC_PREREQ` should be in the first line.
- Use an actual source file for `AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR`.

Also, just call `autoreconf` once and let it take care of which tools to call in which sequence (aclocal, automake, autoconf, autoheader, and whatever else).

Comment: This answer would be improved by clarifying that these changes are sufficient to induce `autoreconf -i` to produce the expected `./aclocal.m4` file (which is true for me).